# Why is the PayPal sandbox telling me my shopping cart is empty?

Tags: php, paypal

On my local machine, when I submit this form, and I do have items inside the `$_SESSION['cart']`, the sandbox does recognize the items inside it. But when I tried it on a live server, and I submitted the form while there's an item inside `$_SESSION['cart']`, the sandbox says my cart is empty... Why is that?

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" <?php if(empty($_SESSION['cart'])){echo "onsubmit=\"return false;\"";} ?>>
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?=$ppemail['email']?>" />
    <?php
        $i = 1;
        foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $qty):
            $product = $myCart->getProduct($id);
    ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="item_name_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $product['ProductName']; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="item_number_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $product['ProductID']; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="amount_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $product['ProductOverridePrice']; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="quantity_<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $qty; ?>">
    <?php
            $i++;
        endforeach;
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
    <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
    <input type="hidden" name="shipping_1" value="<?php echo $shipping; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo $the_class->settings[0]['DomainName'];?>shopping-cart-details.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<?php echo $the_class->settings[0]['DomainName'];?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="<?php echo $the_class->settings[0]['DomainName'];?>classes/paypal.php">
    <input type="image" src="images/continue-btn.png" name="pay now" value="pay" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the bug...the table that was at the live server....i meant, one of the field names was small caps..errr